# Where do I find Orca in Ubuntu Classic

Tags: gnome-classic, orca

Where do I find Orca in Ubuntu Classic?

Answer (score 2):

It should be under `Applications>>Universal Access>>Orca Screen Reader`.

To run it manually:

- Press <kbd>alt+f2</kbd> and type Orca, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If it is not in your menu:

- Right click on the menu and click edit menu, and enable Orca under the "Universal Access" section.

[image: example picture]

Comment: Thanks Roland. I have it set up, and with a great deal of patients. I'm now glad that I was able to develop some patients,Thanks, to a great part, to MSN. - bri <3